# How to get formatting of cells in an Excel file?

Tags: java, excel

I am currently working on a Excel file viewer project in Java. Currently, I'm able to read the file and display cells' data. However, I can't display the formatting of cells. How can I get the formatting of cells from the Excel file? Is there an API or library for this?

Answer (score 0):

[Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) provides the functionality you are asking for.

Comment: As what i know, apache POI only support writing the formatting but not read from excel-sheet right?

Comment: @Soo Ching Pau You can use the org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter class to format the data from a cell, it will use the format of the excel cell if available